# passing object to activity

Tags: android

Can i initialize object in my first activity and you it in all activity???

```
public class Calc{
    int x;
    int y;
    public Calc(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }
    public int sum() {
        return x + y;
    }
}
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ProgressBar loading;
private static int progress;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Calc c = new Calc(3, 4);
}
}


public class PreviewActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.preview);

            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
            txt.setText(Integer.toString(c.sum));
}
}
```

How can i Initialize Calc object in MainActivity and use it PreviewActivity.

How can i pass it to another activity or how can i make it share with other activity

Comment: Why don't you just send sum of Calc in PreviewActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Application` class by extending it and writing your custom `Application` class, and keep your objects in this class that you need in your cross `Activities`

```
class MyApplication extends Application{
    Object a;

    public void setA(Object a){
         this.a = a;
    }

    public Object getA(){
         return a;
    }

}
```

Now lets suppose in your A activity you create object of class `Object` and want to use it in your B Activity.

do it this way,

```
class ActivityA extends Activity(){

...
// some where in activity, set your object this way.
     Object aObj = new Object();
     ((MyApplication)getApplication()).setA(aObj);


...

}

class ActivityB extends Activity(){

...
// some where in activity, get your object this way.
     Object aObj = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getA( );


...

}
```

You need to tell your `androidManifest.xml` about your extended `Application` class.

Answer (score 2):

make

```
public class Calc implements Serializable {
int x;
int y;
public Calc(int x, int y) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
}
public int sum() {
    return x + y;
}
```

}

and

When you start your PreviewActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PreviewActivity .class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data",c);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in your PreviewActivity 
do this

```
Calc c=(Calc ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i pass it to another activity or how can i make it share with
>   other activity

Just use *Intent* so:

```
intent.putExtra("calc" new Calc(3, 4));
```

for passing this `Object` when you want to start another `Activity`.

Then in your second `Activity` just call:

```
Calc c = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("calc"); // getSerializableExtra("calc");
```

And your `Calc` class have to implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`

```
public class Calc implements Parcelable { 
 ...
}
```

Comment: That will not work on its own.  You need to have `Calc` implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable` for this to work.

Comment: Calc should implements `Serializable` to pass it in Intents

Comment: You'll get an error of type `method putExtra(String, Calc)` not found.

Comment: You right, i forgot that in my app class extends from another that implements Parcelable.