# How to Keep XMPP connection alive throughout application?

Tags: android, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How do i pass an object from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

I have one class XmppClient();
instantiating in MainActivity like this

`XmmppClient client = new XmmppClient ();`

and have to use that in another activity how can i keep it alive for my application..

Comment: This has been asked several times on SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2906925/165674 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2696684/165674

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11332586/1436931

Answer (score 1):

You can passing Custom Obejct to Between two Activities:

**1.** Using [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) Class

**2.** By implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface in your `MyView` class

**3.** By implementing [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface in your `MyView` class

Comment: i tried like this but no use. look at my Question i was edited..

Comment: @RajaReddyP : can you tell me what is `client` and where you read we can only pass strings between Activities using bundle or intent?.as  i known we can pass any object or data which implements  Parcelable and Serializable interfaces

Comment: Actually my requirement is different, but i confused about the objects i said like that. now i was edited my question, now you can understand..

Comment: @RajaReddyP : can you past me XmmppClient apiu docs link

Comment: Xmpp api are aSmack library, you can get this in google, just search xmpp smack library.

Comment: @RajaReddyP : only solution for your problem is Application class see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data example how we use Application class for sharing an object or any other data to all activities

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible only if your custom object class implements [**`Parcelable`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

Comment: by using parcelable i can pass string, int of custom values, here there is no custom vales it's function.

Comment: You dont use **Parcelable** to send string, int and other literal values, using **Bundle** is enough for that. You cant pass methods, its only objects which can be passed. Methods are called only.

Comment: look at my Question i was edited now

Comment: In your case, i think you need to use [Observer/Observable](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-howto.html) approach to call methods of an object instance from another class without having reference to it.

Comment: Actually my requirement is i want to keep live one function throughout the application, according to iPhone knowledge i called like that..what is the solution for this..

Comment: then you should override Application class and define it in you AndroidManifest.xml. By this way, you can easily get reference of your application class (using getApplicationContext) and include all the custom  methods you need in that class

Answer (score 0):

One option could be letting your custom class implement Serializable interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using putExtra(Serializable..) variant of the Intent#putExtra() method.

PSEUDO code:

```
//to pass :
   intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```